# Oversized UI in Firefox (non-high DPI display)

Tags: debian, xfce, firefox

When installing Firefox ESR on a fresh bare-bones Debian 10 net-install with the minimal components of Xfce, the UI appears somehow oversized (like it was a touch device, which is not the case). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAT4U.png) and
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCpMV.png) show the issue.

Has anybody faced this issue? Is there a way to solve it rather than reinstalling the OS?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Worth to say that the UI components that are affected are mainly those which are part of the Firefox UI itself, not the webpages. I mean, right-click menus, Firefox top-right menu, as well as the cursor in the URL bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out myself.

Booting my system in recovery mode and deleting the file `/home/<myUser>/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml` has returned Firefox's UI to its default state after I've rebooted normally.

EDIT: turns out it was a problem with the font I had set, changing it solves the issue without deleting any files.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably already aware of these, but in case not...

In the `Customize...` tab, shown below, there should be a `Density` setting that makes UI controls a bit more or less like a touch device.

Also, the size of controls in the `Preferences` tab can be reduced by zooming the page out.

[image: Screenshot of Customize tab]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that option, but even selecting the `Compact` option does not fix the menus size (I mean, right click menus, huge cursor in the URL bar, the Firefox top-right menu...). It's weird...